# Meaning of “on” in "blow on the whistle"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Explain please the meaning of “on” here. Because as far as I know we don’t need any preposition with “blow the whistle”

> The boughs of two chestnut trees grind together, then Eustace blows an
> ‘excruciating noise’ on the whistle he has made from a piece of wood

Comment: We usually say a football referee "blows her whistle", but we might say he blows **on** his whistle to signal the end of the game." Tunes can be played on a musical instrument. And an ‘excruciating noise’ can be blown on a home-made whistle.

Comment: In this case "on" could be replaced with "using."

Comment: We normally use *with* to indicate a tool used to create some effect/result: "made a grinding noise with her teeth", "dug a hole with a spoon", "battered the musician with a guitar". Ironically here, this is often referred to as the **instrumental** use of *with*. When the thing being produced is a sound and is considered musical in some way, however, we use *on* to indicate the instrumental use of an object to produce that sounds. Compare a "Made a  screeching noise with her guitar" and ?"Made a screeching noise on her guitar" b) ?"Played a tune with her guitar" "Played a tune on her guitar".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can blow a whistle.

And you can blow a noise somewhere or somehow or somewhen.

But you cannot blow a noise a whistle, nor can you blow a whistle a noise.

It’s certainly ***possible*** for the verb *blow* to take two different objects, but this is not one of those scenarios. The double-object scenario that works with *blow* is the one where you *blow your mother a kiss*, where *mother* is often referred to as the **indirect object** (which in Old English used to be declined into the now-defunct dative case), the receiving beneficiary of the verb’s **direct object** *kiss* (which used to be declined into the now-defunct accusative case).

But you can’t use an indirect object here because of the “non-benefactive” semantics of the relation between the verb *blow* and the two nouns *noise* and *whistle*.

So you need the preposition to say how or where or when &c the excruciating noise is being blown. That’s why you blow a noise **on** the whistle... **in** your hands... early in the morning... day in and day out... **for** three years. Notice all those adjuncts stacking up. That’s perfectly fine. Just don’t try to interpose one between the verb and its object. That’s not grammatical.

A prepositional phrase is never a [**core argument**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(linguistics)) because it’s not an object. It’s an adjunct, but it might be a *required* **oblique argument** to *blow* in this scenario, because *to blow a noise* may not be perceived by all native speakers as fully grammatical without some sort of adjunct to complete the verb.

---

### *Boring Musings*

If you are Russian as your screen name suggests to me, it may be that you’re asking this question because of some way that Russian does this differently from how English does this. I don’t know Russian, but perhaps it might be possible in Russian to skip the preposition by having the noun for *whistle* declined into a special grammatical case that English doesn’t have, perhaps the instrumental case so it could mean “with” or ”on” the whistle.

English can’t do that here, although strongly inflected languages often can. It’s like the famous Latin saying from which we get *He who lives **by the sword** dies **by the sword**.* Latin had a special case-ending for the ablative case which it could use for its nouns to mean *by the sword*. That’s what the Romans used here instead of a preposition: *Qui gladio ferit, gladio perit*. They didn’t need a preposition like
*cum* (with) to go with their *gladius* (sword). All the Romans had to do was change the case ending and make it *gladio* and they were done.

This one is in the ablative case (in Latin lingo), which is a grammatical case descended from the Proto-Indo-European instrumental case just as Russian’s own instrumental case is. I’m just guessing  but ***perhaps*** Russian is like Latin in this way, provoking your interesting question. English, though, has lost almost all of its original declension system (apart from its personal pronouns). So in English we have to use lots of “little words” that Russian has no need of; no doubt you’ve noticed. :)

Comment: You can teach kids, you can teach maths, you can teach school, and you can teach kids maths, but even in the States you can't teach kids math school.

Answer (score 1):

The verb *play* takes the proposition *on* when a musical instrument is named:

> play ( [a tune / a melody / a few notes / ... ] ) on a [guitar / piano / clarinet / flute / trombone / violin / ...]

Other examples include:

> He banged out a tattoo *on* his drum.

> Play me a tune *on* the piano, Sam...

> He sure can play a mean rift *on* his guitar.

> He sits there for hours at a time, just playing on his instrument.

and so on.

From the [OED entry for play](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00181183;jsessionid=14C779BAA54276BB62FDAC0411A59484):

> **IV. 16. a.** Performance on a musical instrument. *rare*. ? Obs. (Usually *playing*.)

It also applies to records playing on record decks, the radio, and so forth:

> He heard the old rock and roll song playing *on* the dukebox.

Again from [OED entry for play](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00181183;jsessionid=14C779BAA54276BB62FDAC0411A59484):

> **b.** The act of playing a gramophone record. *colloq*.
>
> **1961** in `Webster`. **1963** *Guardian* 15 June 3/7 The juke boxes each achieve 800 ‘plays’ a week. **1967** *Melody Maker* 29 Apr. 10/4 It's nice party dance music‥but the attention tends to wander after a few plays. **1974** Listener 3 Jan. 28/1 About eight records are played on each edition of *Top of the Pops*. That makes for four thousand ‘plays’ in ten years. **1978** *Oxford Times* (City ed.) 13 Jan. 15 A catchy tune with a sprightly arrangement that might make a hit if it gets enough plays on the radio.

However, for locations, *at* is used with playing:

> The latest Tom Hanks movie is playing at the local cinema.