# In "play badminton," what is the logic that makes "badminton" the object of "play"? It almost seems like an adverbial relationship

Tags: grammar, objects

Let's take the sentence "I play badminton every day."
[Lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/definition/play) has "play" here as taking an object in "badminton", with play signifying "take part in".

For some perspective on this, in Chinese, they would say "I play a ball" rather than "I play with a ball". In Chinese, the objective link is very clear. In English, in "I play badminton", I'm confused about the meaning of play that allows for a connection between "play" and "badminton" that is that of a grammatical object rather than an adverbial complement.

Comment: You say that "play badminton" means "take part in badminton", and the second phrase's syntax gives you doubt about the first one. I don't see why it should; it's normal for phrases with different syntaxes to mean the same thing. We're discussing language. We're writing about language. Those sentences mean (more or less) the same thing, and there's a preposition "about" in one of them. I don't see that as casting doubt on the natural idea that "discuss" takes a direct object.

Comment: I've totally edited the body of the question. It's easy to see how discuss takes a direct object. I can see these ideas, and discussing them sort of means metaphorically manipulating those ideas.

Comment: But playing, playing means what? Taking a thing and throwing it around? I'm not doing that with the concept of badminton. Playing means what? Taking part in? Well then if I am participating in something, sorry but that something has an adverbial relationship with the verb. This isn't one of those "phrasal verb" situations.

Comment: I don't see how this is any different to Chinese where verbs like 打 (play, as in sport) and 做 (do) take a direct object. And I don't seem why it's an adverbial situation - you're describing what you're playing not how you are playing. Does "I learn badminton" seem similarly odd? Or "I like badminton"?

Comment: As Stuart F suggests, think of the relationship of *play badminton*--verb and direct object-- the same way you think of the game's relationship with other verbs. For example, you can *learn / teach / play / referee / take up / watch / coach* badminton.

Comment: You're right to have doubts; the 'simple' S-V or S-V-O analyses are questionable when examined in depth. The grammarian Allerton, in _The Handbook of English Linguistics__eds Aarts and McMahon, claims that post-verb noun groups such as those appearing in 'The piano resembled a pianola.' / ... / 'The piano had a stool.' / 'The piano seemed an antique.' should not be considered objects but are 'best regarded as belonging to a slightly different category'.  //// But in your example, S-V-O is universally (I think) regarded as the best interpretation, with 'badminton' – and 'violin' – in ...

Comment: different sets of allowable direct objects for the versatile (not a grammatical term!) verb 'play'.  Other usages: 'O'Sullivan played the blue [ball].' 'Smith played the King of Clubs / his rook.' 'The firemen played the hose on the blazing shed.' 'She played Lady Macbeth.' 'He played the marlin for hours.' //// I'm avoiding fixed verbo-nominal expressions such as 'played a blinder'; 'played hookey'; 'played possum'; 'played havoc with'.

Comment: I suspect that "badminton" is a complement rather than an object, and that *"I played badminton"* is the same as *"I went home"* in which "home" cannot be an object as "to go" is intransitive. *Home* and *badminton* are acting adverbially. (Probably as shortened versions of "to home" and "at badminton." Compare "I played David at badminton."

Comment: @Greybeard  Dictionaries  can really muddy the waters here. They will add senses to a word to justify maintaining a typical type of syntax. But I think 'play' [VT] = 'take part in the sport of' / 'take part in a game of' is reasonable. I did baulk at 'He led them a merry dance' being analysed as ditransitive/benefactive.

Comment: The semantic relation between transitive verbs and their direct objects is enormously variable. Every verb has its own unique semantic requirements and provisions for direct objecthood. Effectively, they are part of the meaning of the verb, like the differences among _tell, say, report, ask, request,_ and other speech verbs. And that's only one category our of thousands.

Comment: Could we apply the meaning of play in "he played his rook" to play in "he played badminton"? Perhaps if we think of badminton as all the moving parts involved in that game, as a "mass noun". That would make sense. But if we have to focus on playing singular, more concrete objects, then the shortening from "playing at badminton" might make sense? Also I don't know the historical usage, I wonder what the OED has.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in your sentence "I play badminton", *badminton* is the object of *play*.

Let's start with syntax.

> 2. Position occupied: In languages with strict word order, the subject and the object tend to occupy set positions in unmarked declarative clauses.
>    [-wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(grammar)#Identification)

You accept that "I play the piano" has "the piano" as the object (although this statement is too strong in general - see footnote below). The position occupied by *badminton* is the same as that occupied by *the piano* - it comes after the active verb. Therefore you should also accept that *badminton* is also the object in that position.

The difference between the two nouns is that "the piano" is deemed (so it would seem) a tangible thing that you can physically play, whereas "badminton" is more abstract - it's neither the racket or the shuttlecock, but refers to the game as a whole.

In this sense, "I play piano" uses a similar idea. Here, "piano" doesn't refer to the instrument alone, but to the whole experience including the score, the dynamics, and so on. I'd argue that adding the definite article doesn't necessarily change this sense - it just highlights the instrument in contrast to, say, the flute or the violin. Oddly enough, using an indefinite article pulls the sense back to the physical object.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/play) distinguishes between the senses of *participation* (definition 2) and *performance* (definition 5). This is the distinction you make between *badminton* and *piano*. However, in your examples, both are objects to the verb *play*. "Object" is a grammatical designation that is not affected by the sense of the verb.

There is one more item to consider: if you replace "play" with "take part in" (or participate in), does the need for the word "in" affect whether *badminton* is considered an object?

The answer is that it doesn't. The grammatical role assigned to a word isn't determined by the word - it is determined by the sentence. So if you change the sentence, it is not surprising if the role changes.

In the substitution you highlighted, "take part" is similar to the intransitive ["participate"](https://www.lexico.com/definition/participate), whereas "play" is transitive. That explains the use of the prepositional phrase instead of just a simple noun.

---

Footnote

As [@Araucaria](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/76472/araucaria-not-here-any-more) notes, parallel syntax only suggests parallel function but doesn't always imply it. He gives the counterexample of "I play every week", where noun phrase "every week" is in the same position as "badminton" but functions as a temporal adjunct rather than a direct object.

He also [supplies](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/586957/in-play-badminton-what-is-the-logic-that-makes-badminton-the-object-of-pla/586969?noredirect=1#comment1470644_586969) a test that *badminton* is a noun, not an adverb:

> clauses with "play badminton" can often be passivised: "Badminton is played around the globe", for example. You can't passivise adverbials only objects of verbs and prespositions, in English.

Comment: thank you. Actually, I've modified the title of my question. Originally I had wanted to make sure I was following guidelines for good questions, so I had made it a yes or no question. But actually my real intent is as the question is now. I hope it's not too much to ask you to have a crack at it again.

Comment: @peisander There was one part that I left out. I'm adding that now - have a look once it's up and see if it resolves your query.

Comment: @peisander Regarding the new title - in what sense do you consider "play" or "badminton" an adverb?

Comment: Well it seems that "badminton" in "play badminton" describes the way in which we are playing.

Comment: @peisander No, "badly" or "well" describes the way in which you are playing. "Badminton" is the game/sport you're playing.

Comment: I am playing. How am I playing? I am using a racket to smash a shuttlecock. That's how I am disporting myself.

Comment: For some perspective on this, in Chinese, they would say "I play a ball" rather than "I play with a ball". In Chinese, the objective link is very clear. In English, in "I play badminton", I'm confused about the meaning of play that allows for a connection between "play" and "badminton" that is that of a grammatical object rather than an adverbial complement.

Comment: @peisander _Badminton_ is a noun, not an adjective. It doesn't describe something else. It is a label for a game, like _soccer_, _basketball_, or _table tennis_.

Comment: @peisander I think “badminton” answers the question of “what” you play much better than “how” you play. Hence, object function seems better than adverb function.

Comment: Thanks @Araucaria, good points. I was intending to start with syntax and then address the complexities, but didn't get there. I'll add your points to my answer.

Comment: It's like how you can play nights at the club or you can play knights in your chess match, but when it comes to passives, only knights can be played, never nights. ❌ *Nights have always been played here* isn’t an acceptable passivization.

Answer (score 2):

(This got too long for a comment.)

When the first syn­tac­tic con­stituent you en­counter immediately af­ter a
verb is some noun phrase, your best bet is al­ways going to be that you’re
look­ing at that verb’s **direct ob­ject** (or else some­times that ver­b’s
**pred­i­cate com­ple­ment** if the verb is­n’t be­ing used tran­si­tively). As­sum­ing some ‘miss­ing’ prepo­si­tion that would al­low you to infer an
ad­ver­bial re­la­tion­ship is never the most likely pos­si­ble
read­ing — and most peo­ple can’t spot it happening even in those few such cases that *do*
legitimately arise.

This is true no mat­ter whether you play songs, play poker, play
havoc, play gui­tar, play hookie, play mother, play pos­sum, play
soc­cer, play your­self, play the fool, play the odds, play the
field, play the ponies, play Ohio State, play some­place new, play
cops and rob­bers, play his love in­ter­est, play a fish on the
line, play lounges and tav­erns, play nights and week­ends, play
the Queen of Hearts, play the Prince of Den­mark, play “Some­where
Over the Rain­bow”, play both ends against the mid­dle, or play a
laser beam across the ceil­ing.

See also [this an­swer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/585738/2085).

Comment: Note also that we say can say both "He played small parts" and "He played small towns."